# Install third party package using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed a package using command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade ShopifyAPI
```

> Requirement already up-to-date: ShopifyAPI in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages Requirement already up-to-date:
>   pyactiveresource>=2.1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
>   (from ShopifyAPI) Requirement already up-to-date: PyYAML in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from ShopifyAPI) Requirement
>   already up-to-date: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
>   (from ShopifyAPI)

Also I wanted to use it in jupyter notebook:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ShopifyAPI
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - shopifyapi

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

**Is there any way I can use the package in notebook that was installed using pip3 install command or install those packages using conda?**

Comment: Do you have two different Python installations, like an Anaconda one and a Python.org one or a distro package? If so, they have separate site-packages collections, and you cannot do this.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you only have Anaconda Python, [you can use the `pip` that it comes with](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages). But after installing it via `pip`, you don't try to also `conda install` it; you just use it.

Comment: To answer your direct question at the end: (1) Yes, of course you can use the package in a notebook that was installed using `pip3`, as long as it's the `pip3` for the same Python you're using to run Jupyter; just try it instead of asking whether it would work. (2) No, you cannot install packages that don't exist for conda using conda, because they don't exist. Unless you want to do the packaging yourself. Just use `pip` for them.

Comment: Yes I have two different python installations, one that came default in Ubuntu 16 and another with anaconda. Do I have to create a separate environment in order to use this package in notebook ?
When I install it using pip3 in anaconda's environment, it says package has already been satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two different Python installations (one from your OS, one from Anaconda), they each have their own separate `site-packages`. What you install for one doesn't get installed for the other.

It doesn't actually matter which tool you use—packages installed with the Anaconda installation's `pip` go into the Anaconda site-packages, just like packages installed with its `conda`; only packages installed with the other installation's `pip` don't. But this can get very confusing—you have two different programs named `pip` (or `pip3`) that do different things.

Presumably you already know how to *run* one particular Python or the other; you can run a particular Python's pip by doing `/however/you/run/that/python -m pip`.

Anyway, it looks like you've installed Jupyter for your system Python, but want to use it with Anaconda packages. If so, the solution is either of these:

- Install Jupyter for Anaconda (I think it comes with the full commercial version, and can be `conda install`ed with the mini version?) and use the Anaconda Jupyter.
- Install those packages for the system Python instead of the Anaconda one. (Here you only have `pip` as an option), and use the system Python Jupyter.

Comment: Actually jupyter was installed for Anaconda. Now I installed it for System python also. Working great. Thank you.